# Mask phone numbers with (XXX-XXX-XXXX) in a Text C#

Tags: c#, replace

I am trying to mask the phone number from a text file that gets captured in richtextbox.Text
from a log file .I am unable to get a proper logic based on the indexes ,since the text indexes changes based on the length of the log file.The log file starts with every import dates .e,g today's date

**The contents from richTextBox2.Text :**

```
Started: 11/11/2022 01:20:04 AM.

Import started for period [11/09/2022] to [11/10/2022].

Creating connection to tocco SQL server on SQL03-DM... ok.
Creating connection to Oracle database on TPROD... ok.

Checking for new completes... 10 found (may already exist in Comtel).

--> Checking home number 5811232 (123-001-8956) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 01 ... Recruitment Reception TV... Cell ID 8072 ... Q1CANS Length 0 and Q1DANS Lenth 0 ... Prai home (G2)... ok.
--> Checking home number 5791211 (456-806-0737) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 01 ... Recruitment Reception CABLE ... Cell ID 4410 ... Q1CANS Length 0 and Q1DANS Lenth 0 ... Queco home (G2)... ok.
--> Checking home number 5810404 (789-876-8864) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 01 ... Recruitment Reception TV ... Cell ID 4410 ... Q1CANS Length 0 and Q1DANS Lenth 0 ... Quenco home (G2)... ok.
--> Checking home number 5804303 (101-985-5632) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 03 ... Recruitment Reception DIGITAL ... Cell ID 9081 ... Q1CANS Length 0 and Q1DANS Lenth 0 ... Vaome (G2)... ok.
--> Checking home number 5812793 (111-586-5998) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 01 ... Recruitment Reception DIGITAL ... Cell ID 8062 ... Q1CANS Length 0 and Q1DANS Lenth 0 ... Came (G2)... ok.
--> Checking home number 5811594 (112-670-7592) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 01 ... Recruitment Reception DIGITAL ... Cell ID 8062 ... Q1CANS Length 0 and Q1DANS Lenth 0 ... Caome (G2)... ok.
--> Checking home number 5811925 (113-599-8694) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 01 ... Recruitment Reception DIGITAL ... Cell ID 8112 ... Q1CANS Length 0 and Q1DANS Lenth 0 ... Edmome (G2)... ok.
--> Checking home number 5792492 (114-908-8636) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 03 ... Recruitment Reception DIGITAL ... Cell ID 9086 ... Q1CANS Length 0 and Q1DANS Lenth 0 ... Vancoume (G2)... ok.
--> Checking home number 5822459 (115-112-2693) in Comtel. Inserting... Home Sub Status 01 ... Recruitment Recep


10 home(s) added to Comtel.
   0 home(s) skipped.

Import completed successfully.
```

**My code**

```
  if (filedata.Contains("Started: " + value))
                {
                    int indexOfMessage = filedata.IndexOf("Started: " + value);
                    
            
                    //int indexOfMessage = filedata.IndexOf("Started: " + value);

                    int indexofData = filedata.IndexOf("Ended: " + value);
                    string message = filedata.Substring(indexOfMessage, indexofData - indexOfMessage);
                    richTextBox2.Text = message;
                    

                        if (richTextBox2.Text.Contains("--> Checking home number"))
                        {
                          
                           // string message2 = richTextBox2.Text.Substring(indexOfMessage2, indexofData2 - indexOfMessage2);
                         
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to mask the phone number before it goes into the log file? Or is the text box displaying what's in the log file, and when you display it you want to mask the phone number?

Comment: I want to mask the phone numbers in the richtextbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("Checking home number"))
                        {
                            List<string> phoneList = new List<string>();
                            Regex rg = new Regex(@"\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})");
                            MatchCollection m = rg.Matches(richTextBox1.Text);
                            string Finalstring = rg.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "");
                            richTextBox1.Text = Finalstring; 
                        }
```